# Toolbar not hiding when scrolling is stopped

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to get my toolbar to hide when user is idle and appear when user scroll up. using the layout below, unfortunately I am getting a "close but no cigar" result... As you can see the toolbar is a space above where it should be to achieve the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

                    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshsharing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/post_back">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/posted_list"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/toolbarview">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/theToolbar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:elevation="6dp"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/action_setup"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:id="@+id/action_setup" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ceppi_half"
                            android:id="@+id/ceppi"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/post_button"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/action_setup"
                            android:id="@+id/action_post" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoutbtn"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/action_post"
                            android:id="@+id/action_logout" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tutorial"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:id="@+id/action_tutorial" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I already got the showing and hiding mechanism going but unfortunately... it looks like [image: this] when idle

And like [image: this] when I scroll up...

If only I could get that toolbar to be where the invisible space is in picture 2... everything will be perfect.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post an image of the design you require.

Comment: Hi @KartikSharma first of all, thanks for taking the time to review this... hmm I am not sure if the image will help but here it is ![screen](http://imgur.com/uzY3Hlr)

so this is how i want it to look when the user touch the screen to scroll and see the items in the recyclerview. But when user is idle, the toolbar below it should slide down.

right now, the user has to slide alllllll the way down to the last item in the recyclerview for the toolbar to pop out.

many thanks!